# How can I extract the coordinates from one layer and import them in a diferent layer when key field is the same?

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers

I'm working with 2 different layers. 
   First one is a csv file with 3 fields. Name, longitude and latitude.
   Second is a text file with the field name.

I want to assign the longitude and latitude fields to the second layer when the name coincides, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: This sounds like an excel-task to me, not like one for QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the CSV to QGIS as a Delimited Text layer, using the latitude column as the X coordinate and the longitude column as the Y coordinate.

   - For more details about adding a delimited text table, see [this tutorial](https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/ImportData).
2. Add the text file as a delimited text layer without geometry.
3. Open the layer properties for the CSV > Joins. Join the text table to the CSV, using the name fields as the common field.

   - For more details on performing a table join in QGIS, see [this tutorial](https://www.gislounge.com/working-with-tables-mastering-qgis/).

---

Or, as Erik suggested, you can combine the tables in Excel.